# Select top row melted data after sorting by value

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I have the following melted data:

```
dat.melt <- structure(list(CellTypes = structure(c(62L, 35L, 73L, 45L, 14L, 
22L, 46L, 13L, 68L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 64L, 24L, 72L, 58L, 51L, 9L, 
60L, 37L, 34L, 49L, 33L, 2L, 50L, 32L, 11L, 52L, 44L, 66L, 8L, 
5L, 47L, 59L, 53L, 7L, 6L, 77L, 75L, 17L, 27L, 61L, 20L, 18L, 
19L, 16L, 54L, 15L, 41L, 3L, 63L, 48L, 57L, 43L, 70L, 40L, 12L, 
76L, 74L, 29L, 28L, 25L, 30L, 42L, 39L, 56L, 4L, 67L, 71L, 31L, 
36L, 23L, 38L, 69L, 55L, 26L, 65L, 62L, 35L, 73L, 45L, 14L, 22L, 
46L, 13L, 68L, 21L, 1L, 10L, 64L, 24L, 72L, 58L, 51L, 9L, 60L, 
37L, 34L, 49L, 33L, 2L, 50L, 32L, 11L, 52L, 44L, 66L, 8L, 5L, 
47L, 59L, 53L, 7L, 6L, 77L, 75L, 17L, 27L, 61L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 
16L, 54L, 15L, 41L, 3L, 63L, 48L, 57L, 43L, 70L, 40L, 12L, 76L, 
74L, 29L, 28L, 25L, 30L, 42L, 39L, 56L, 4L, 67L, 71L, 31L, 36L, 
23L, 38L, 69L, 55L, 26L, 65L), .Label = c("3T3-L1", "Adipose Brown", 
"Adipose White", "Adrenal Gland", "B Cells (GL7 neg; Alum)", 
"B Cells (GL7 neg; KLH)", "B Cells (GL7 pos; Alum)", "B Cells (GL7 pos; KLH)", 
"B Cells Marginal Zone", "B220+ Dend. Cells", "BA/F3", "Bladder", 
"Bone", "Bone Marrow", "C2C12", "CD4+ SP Thymoctyes", "CD4+ T cells", 
"CD4+/CD8+ DP Thymocytes", "CD8+ SP Thymocytes", "CD8+ T cells", 
"CD8a+ Dend. Cells Lymphoid", "CD8a+ Dend. Cells Myeloid", "Ciliary Bodies", 
"Common Myeloid Progenitor", "Cornea", "Dorsal Root Ganglia", 
"Embryonic Fibroblasts", "Embryonic Stem Line Bruce4 P13", "Embryonic Stem Line V26 2 P16", 
"Epidermis", "Eyecup", "Follicular B Cells", "Foxp3+ Tcells", 
"Granulo Monoprogenitor", "Granulocytes", "Heart", "Hematopoietic Stem Cells", 
"Iris", "Kidney", "Lacrimal Gland", "Large Intestine", "Lens", 
"Liver", "Lung", "Lymph Nodes", "Macrophage Peri ", "Mammary Gland", 
"Mammary Gland Non-Lactating", "Mast Cells", "Mast Cells IgE", 
"Mast Cells IgE 1hr", "Mast Cells IgE 6hr", "Megaerythrocyte Progenitor", 
"mIMCD-3 Cells", "MIN6 cells", "Neuro2a Neuroblastoma Cells", 
"NIH 3T3", "NK Cells", "Osteoblast Day14", "Osteoblast Day21", 
"Osteoblast Day5", "Osteoclasts", "Ovary", "Pancreas", "Pituitary", 
"Placenta", "Prostate", "RAW 264.7 Cells", "Retinal Pigment Epithelium", 
"Salivary Gland", "Skeletal Muscle", "Small Intestine", "Spleen", 
"Stem Cells C3H/10T1/2", "Stomach", "Umbilical Cord", "Uterus"
), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("LPS_IV_SP", "MPL_IV_SP"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(3.647, 33.629, 17.838, 33.917, 29.66, 31.694, 32.603, 
    24.152, 19.969, 24.012, 40.101, 12.682, 0.323, 12.846, 5.087, 
    11.707, 16.682, 7.71, 22.472, 10.21, 10.109, 12.643, 12.623, 
    1.48, 13.075, 5.042, 12.19, 11.691, 15.24, 17.073, 5.854, 
    5.188, 11.983, 18.679, 6.406, 4.474, 5.445, 8.144, 0.739, 
    3.652, 14.232, 17.1, 2.603, 1.762, 1.993, 3.475, 10.305, 
    7.457, 1.189, 2.895, 4.181, 3.06, 5.885, 3.063, 2.532, 1.662, 
    3.86, 5.094, 5.916, 4.553, 3.703, 2.546, 0.764, 0.597, 1.39, 
    2.933, 0.665, 0.121, 0.257, 0.764, 0.196, 0.208, 0.232, 0.001, 
    0.004, 0.035, 0.036, 56.156, 53.485, 48.206, 45.975, 41.067, 
    40.581, 38.155, 33.009, 29.468, 29.219, 27.945, 19.165, 15.985, 
    15.682, 15.077, 14.72, 13.856, 13.576, 12.914, 12.77, 12.577, 
    12.526, 11.05, 10.532, 10.008, 9.942, 9.238, 8.67, 8.237, 
    7.938, 7.819, 7.55, 7.349, 7.217, 7.146, 6.158, 5.852, 5.368, 
    5.328, 5.126, 4.887, 4.767, 4.24, 3.858, 3.816, 3.676, 3.318, 
    3.118, 2.459, 2.269, 2.266, 2.201, 1.467, 1.418, 1.368, 1.267, 
    1.077, 1.022, 0.835, 0.667, 0.655, 0.609, 0.53, 0.452, 0.24, 
    0.239, 0.211, 0.124, 0.084, 0.05, 0.028, 0.024, 0.016, 0.007, 
    0.006, 0.003, 0.002)), row.names = c(NA, -154L), .Names = c("CellTypes", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> tail(dat.melt,n=5L)
                     CellTypes  variable value
150                       Iris MPL_IV_SP 0.016
151 Retinal Pigment Epithelium MPL_IV_SP 0.007
152                 MIN6 cells MPL_IV_SP 0.006
153        Dorsal Root Ganglia MPL_IV_SP 0.003
154                  Pituitary MPL_IV_SP 0.002
> head(dat.melt,n=5L)
     CellTypes  variable  value
1  Osteoclasts LPS_IV_SP  3.647
2 Granulocytes LPS_IV_SP 33.629
3       Spleen LPS_IV_SP 17.838
4  Lymph Nodes LPS_IV_SP 33.917
5  Bone Marrow LPS_IV_SP 29.660
>
```

For each variable `MPL_IV_SP` and `LPS_IV_SP` I would like to select top-5 rows ('cell type') sorted descending by values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
dat.melt %>%
      group_by(variable) %>%
      top_n(5, value)
```

NOTE: In the other answer, there is no `sort`ing done.  But, I can understand the biased voting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do using data.table package as well. Below is the code:

```
library(data.table)
dat.melt <- data.table(dat.melt)
dat.melt[, .SD[1:5], by=variable]
```

The advantage of data.table is that it is faster than data.frame.